# No IE7 contextmenu in Tridion 2009SP1

Tags: cme

Just installed a fresh copy of Tridion 2009 SP1 on a default Windows Server 2008 virtual image.

The IE7 contextmenu, right mouse click, does not show e.g. the properties of a Page, like Checkin.

Which hotfix number solves this problem?
From SDL Tridion World > 2009 SP1 > Hotfixes does not show a descriptive message which hotfix solves this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please [Configuring your Web browser for Content Manager Explorer](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_43B1609144D94562A394BB51FAC884B9) (Requires Login)- it should resolve your problem

Comment: HR1 and HR2 are for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, not 2009. We don't support 2009 anymore... so any new issues aren't going to be solved by SDL.

Comment: I am sorry i did not notice 2009

Comment: You accepted the answer, Tuesday. So, did it work? On older setups, a virtual machine in the network could recreate a (once) supported browser setup, otherwise compatibility mode (and sometimes just refreshing) has helped me. Even without the context menu, many options are available in the top buttons (now called the ribbon toolbar).